# Server 2016 with two nodes + failover cluster manager

Tags: storage-spaces

Hoping someone can assist. We've got two physical servers running 2016 running running a failover cluster manager environment. Each server has the following hard disks installed.

6 x 600GB 15k SAS on storage controller 1

2 x 600GB 15k SAS (mirrored as used by host OS) on storage controller 2

4 x 960GB SSDs on storage controller 2

We've got one storage pool presented to failover cluster manager and then running two CSV's. One of the CSVs was running out of space therefore we decided to install an additional 2 x 960SSDs on each server to provision more space.

When we check the storage pool I can see it says 2.18TB of free space. When I go to extend the CSV's with the assumption I've got 2.18TB of free space, I cannot increase the size of the CSV by that amount - at the moment the only amount I can extend it by is 50GB which is not making a lot of sense to me. Why? I've already optimized the storage pool with little effect. I've also rescanned the the storage pool again with little effect.

Please see below some outputs:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZokF.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsFbG.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qM0DT.png)

In the output above, the disks labelled "ATA VK000960GWTHB" are the new ones.

Comment: Are you using Clustered Storage Spaces as a back-end for your CSVs?

Comment: Hi - yes I am..

Comment: Please see some more screenshots for your reference.
https://imgur.com/fgJgEqJ

Answer (score 3):

I assume you are using Storage Spaces Direct. In this case you would need to add NVMe drives to be able to use SSDs for capacity Tier. More information: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/storage-spaces/understand-the-cache.

You will need to add more HDDs to your server to be able to extend you CSVs.